# Why callback function in "repeated component" always points to the last component that is repeated in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular app that repeats a component five times (e.g.)

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#someData of someDataThatGoesForFiveTimes; #ind=index">
   <componentThatIsRepeated [somecount]="ind">
   </componentThatIsRepeated>
```

This is the component that is repeated.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'componentThatIsRepeated',
      template: `
        <componentThatOutputs  (outputEvent) = "callbackFn()">
        <p>Just some random template</p>
      `
    })

    export class ComponentThatIsRepeated {

        @Input() somecount: number;

        public callbackFn():void{

        console.log("For some reason, any click any of the 5 components, I receive this.somecount as 5")  //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    }
```

This is the component that emits the event/callback.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'componentThatOutputs',
      template: `<button type="button"  (click) ="YouClickedMe()" >Click Me!</button>  `
    })

    export class ComponentThatOutputs {


        @Output()   outputEvent = new EventEmmmiter<any>();

            public YouClickedMe():void{
            this.outputEvent.emit("abc");



    }
```

However, as mention in the comment in `ComponentThatIsRepeated`, why do I always receive this.somecount as 5 upon clicking say e.g. 1st component. I expect each component click respectively to log 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Why is this happening and any solution is highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the component you are repeating the `componentThatIsRepeated` you have to change the `ngFor` like below,

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="#someData of someDataThatGoesForFiveTimes; #ind=index">
       <componentThatIsRepeated [somecount]="ind">
       </componentThatIsRepeated>
   </li>
</ul>

<!-- For newer angular versions use below-->
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let someData of someDataThatGoesForFiveTimes; let ind=index">
       <componentThatIsRepeated [somecount]="ind">
       </componentThatIsRepeated>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then the `someCount` will be respectively 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. You might need to add 1 for the `someCount` if you need to get 1,2,3,4,5 as the output.